# Creating a project with a default blank activity vs manually adding a blank activity

Tags: android, android-activity

So I was watching an android tutorial where the narrator explained how to manually add a blank activity to a project with no activity instead of picking a default blank activity when creating the project. On his screen, both blank activities had the same java source code.

However, when I tried this, I found that the blank activity I added manually was lacking the `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` methods in the `.java` file. Is there a reason why the manually added activity is missing these methods, and is this a significant difference?

The link for the tutorial is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOYzJN6A-JM, and a comparison of the two java codes is below.

This is the java code from the default blank activity when the project was created.
[image]

This is the java code from the manually added blank activity to a project with no activity.[image]

Comment: When we use new version of android studio,it doesnt add those functions by default.old versions have those functions.

Comment: I'm using the same version of android for both of these blank activities though, so shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Android versions may be same but this update is made for android studio.Old versions of android studio had those functions but new version i.e 1.5 doesnt have those.